# Warning about possible thrown exceptions in Scala

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, lint

Scala usually (apart from intrinsically error-prone things like I/O) keeps me from inadvertently shooting myself in the foot by virtue of its type checking system. But there are some features (which I sometimes need), like `Map#apply()`, or `List#head` that may throw errors.

Is there a way to tell the Scala compiler to warn me when I call something that may throw?

I realize these warnings might turn into a deluge as you go down the JVM rabbit hole, so I expect I'd need to filter out `OutOfMemoryError` and its kin, but I'm okay with that. Scala, as a platform, seems to be very much about safety, so I figure I'm just missing something simple — but Googling around for Scala warning options left me with only the `-unchecked`, `-deprecation`, and `-feature` flags, all of which I'm already using.

Answer (score 2):

[WartRemover](https://github.com/puffnfresh/wartremover) can give you warnings for some of the more common problems with partial functions in the Scala core library.